# get the most negative number's absolute value

Tags: c

In the abs's man manual, there's a NOTES: Trying to take the absolute value of the most negative integer is not defined.

And the prototype of abs is：`int abs(int j);`

Why does abs return `int`? As the return value will be positive, why not return `unsigned int`?

If abs returned `unsigned int`, the solution of the most negative integer's absolute value is simple like this:

```
if(INT_MIN == j) 
  return (unsigned int)j;
```

Comment: The chances are that the specification of `abs()` was finalized before C had `unsigned` types at all.

Comment: I think it's the right answer,thanks a lot @Jonathan Leffler

Answer (score 4):

There are a variety of issues in mixing signed and unsigned values in calculations, so the question would be: What are most users going to do with the result of calling `abs(int)`?  I think the most likely answer - or at least a very common one - is that they'll do further arithmetic with the result.  In that case, you almost surely want to stay within `int` rather than getting back an `unsigned`.

Here's another post on mixing signed with unsigned in calculations: [what happens when i mix signed and unsigned types ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609091/what-happens-when-i-mix-signed-and-unsigned-types)

Answer (score -2):

A 16 bit signed integer has a range of `-32768` to `+32767`

So `INT_MIN` will be `-32768`. The absolute value of that is outside the range of an integer. Therefore it is not defined.