# C++ bool gets random/wrong value?

Tags: c++, debugging, boolean

While debugging my code I have noticed that something strange is going on, So I have added more lines and got confused even more:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Node
{
    size_t size = 0;
};

class MallocMetadata {
public:
    size_t size; /** Effective allocation - requested size **/
    bool is_free;
    MallocMetadata *next;
    MallocMetadata *prev;
    MallocMetadata *next_free;
    MallocMetadata *prev_free;
};

int main()
{
    size_t size = 0;
    auto node = std::make_shared<Node>();
    int tmp_res=node->size - size - sizeof(MallocMetadata);
    bool test=(node->size - size - sizeof(MallocMetadata)) < 128;
    bool test1=tmp_res<128;
    std::cout << tmp_res << "\n";
    std::cout << test << "\n";
    std::cout << test1 << "\n";
}
```

After running these 3 lines I saw:

```
tmp_res=-48
test = false
test1 = true
```

How is this even possible! why `test` is false, -48 is smaller than 128

Here's a proof:

[image]

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles the code is enormous that it can't be split. I swear  tried too hard but unless you don't want to see 700 lines it's hard.

Comment: Change the code to: `auto tmp_res=node->size - size - sizeof(MallocMetadata);`

Comment: you dont need enormous code to show us the types of the variables involved. It does not matter that `size` is member of some `node` but we need to know its type

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number for that I have updated the question

Comment: What are the values of `node->size` and `sizeof(MallocMetadata)`?

Comment: what is `size` ? I mean the one that is not member of `node` ?

Comment: Please, note that `sizeof` returns `size_t` which is an unsigned type. Negative values, expressed in unsigned result in (possibly huge) positive values. Hence, `node->size - size - sizeof(MallocMetadata)` may be not `< 128` while casted to `int` it is.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it's 4 please notice the image the value is written there

Comment: what type is it? Please do read the link that was posted in the first comment: [mcve]

Comment: @Scheff'sCat but the result is saved in int not in size_t

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that's in my question too you can clearly see it's size_t in the signature...

Comment: I've added a [mre] for you

Comment: please consider that not everybody can view images. Code should be posted as code not as images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question. I don't understand why asking for the code in questions about code ends in a discussion that often. Hrmpf. Nevermind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the part `node->size - size - sizeof(MallocMetadata)` is calculated in unsigned integer.

When calculation of unsigned integer is going to be negative, the maximum number of the type plus one is added and the result wraparounds.

Therefore, the value looks like being big value (128 or more), making the expression `(node->size - size - sizeof(MallocMetadata)) < 128` false.

In the other hands, `int tmp_res=node->size - size - sizeof(MallocMetadata);` will convert the big value to `int`. `int` is signed and it may give different value than the expression above that doesn't perform convertion to `int`.

Comment: @mick `bool test2 = node->size < 128 + size + sizeof(MallocMetadata);`? (if `size` won't be too big)

Comment: How is this the same? I want their sum to be less that 128 not only `node->size`

Comment: @mick basic algebra `a - b - c < d === a < d + b + c`

Comment: just now saw it but again why this happened? The result (which should be negative) was saved in int not size_t so it should be correct. @AlanBirtles

Comment: `tmp_res` is an `int` and using it in `test1` gives you the correct result however the left hand side of the inequality when assigning to `test` only contains `size_t` variables so it is calculated as an unsigned `size_t` resulting in a large positive number which is not less than `128`

Comment: I'm a little disappointed and concerned to see at least 2 people agreed with the "How is this the same" comment, when this is basic algebra that is learned in grade-school...

Answer (score 0):

I believe whenever there is an unsigned value in an expression, the result tends to be unsigned aswell.

```
size_t size = 0;
auto val = 1 + 100 + (-100) + size;
std::cout << typeid(val).name();
```

'val' will be a size_t aswell. So in your case, you're trying to store a negative value in size_t which causes overflow.
You can explicitly typecast it to a signed integer and that should be enough if I'm not mistaken.Like so:

```
bool test=int(node->size - size - sizeof(MallocMetadata)) < 128;
```

Comment: `whenever there is an unsigned value in an expression, the result tends to be unsigned aswell`, not necessarily: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609091/what-happens-when-i-mix-signed-and-unsigned-types https://godbolt.org/z/cj6YqYYn8

Comment: note that the cast relies on signed integer overflow which is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c)

Comment: Oh, correct. I was just considering same width types, mb.
About the note, I'll look into it. Thanks for corrections.