# how c++ handles the arithmetic between an int and an unsigned int?

Tags: c++, integer, unsigned-integer

I am a beginner in cpp, reading about the topic *Type-conversions*. I want to ask how cpp handles the arithmetic between an `int` and an `unsigned int` inernally to calculate the result?

For example, something like:

```
long int result = a-variable-in-int + a-variable-in-unsigned-int
```

I am interested in knowing the basic concept that goes inside the cpp compiler for running this expression. If someone can explain this in simple terms, that would be helpful...

Comment: This question has been asked before, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609091/what-happens-when-i-mix-signed-and-unsigned-types

Comment: @PKramer my bad, thanks for pointing it out