# How do the augmented assignment operators in C behave when the signedness of the operands do not match?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, unsigned, signed, augmented-assignment

I have seen [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25609091/16217248) but mine is specifically referring to the augmented assignment operators such as `+=`, `-=`, etc. How exactly do the those operators work when I have the following?

```
extern signed s;
extern unsigned u;
s += u;
```

Will this be equivalent to this?

```
s = (signed)((unsigned)s+u);
```

More specifically would this invoke undefined behavior due to signed integer overflow?

```
signed s = INT_MAX;
unsigned u = 1;
s += u;
```

I am aware that when using the normal arithmetic operators, the unsigned type usually dominates. However, I am not sure if this holds true for the augmented assignment operators.

Comment: `x <op>= y` is defined to be equivalent to `x = x <op> y;` except that `x` is only evalulated once. Type handling is the same as the expanded form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
s += u;
```

Is the same as this:

```
s = s + u;
```

As per section 6.5.16.2p3 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A compound assignment of the form `E1 op = E2` is equivalent to the
> simple assignment expression `E1 = E1 op (E2)`, except that the lvalue
> `E1` is evaluated only once, and with respect to an
> indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of a compound
> assignment is a single evaluation

So first `s + u` is evaluated.  This causes `s` to be converted to type `unsigned` as per the usual arithmetic conversions, and the result is unsigned.  Then this result is assigned back to `s` which undergoes a conversion from `unsigned` to `signed`.

So in this particular case:

```
signed s = INT_MAX;
unsigned u = 1;
s += u;
```

The value of `s` is converted to `unsigned` and 1 is added to it, resulting in an unsigned value of `INT_MAX + 1`.  This value is then converted to `signed`, which undergoes an implementation defined conversion due to the value being out of range as per section 6.3.1.3p3:

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new
> type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
> can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
> the new type.
>
> *3* **Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
> implementation-defined signal is raised.**

So the above does not have undefined behavior, but it does have implementation defined behavior.