# Casting inside a ternary operator causes underflow

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, underflow

I have the following snippet of code

```
   #include <iostream>

   int main() {

   int64_t res;
   int some_val = 5;

   if(false)
   {
       res = static_cast<uint32_t>(some_val);
   }
   else
   {
       res = -1;
   }
   std::cout << "first check: " << res << std::endl;

   res = (false) ? static_cast<uint32_t>(some_val) : (-1);
   std::cout << "second check: " << res << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, the stream output is:

first check: -1

second check: 4294967295

whereas I would've expected both checks to return -1, given that they're basically the same exact expression.

I read the documentation and it says that the operator "?" should convert the 2 values to a common type, so I would've expected int64_t to be picked(which would allow for both datatypes to be represented) but this is clearly not the case and instead uint32_t is chosen, which causes the underflow when casted to -1.

Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

Comment: Aside, there is no such thing as "integer underflow".

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI there is, but you need to be using binary `-`, `-=` or `--`, you don't get underflow with unary `-`

Comment: @Caleth [Underflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow) only exists in floating point arithmetic. Integers only have overflow, whether you add, subtract, or multiply.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI that's not the definition I'm familiar with. I would call wraparound the grouping of overflow and underflow

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI the terminology "underflow" as "overflow" on the negative end is commonly accepted. See [Wikipedia article on integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). See [C++ Core Guidelines ES.104 Don't underflow](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-underflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional operator converts its operands to a common type. In your case:

```cpp
res = (false) ? static_cast<uint32_t>(some_val) : (-1);
```

The two sides of conditional operator are of type `uint32_t` and `int` respectively. Assuming that `uint32_t` is a type alias for `unsigned int`, the `-1` (of type `int`) is converted to `unsigned int`.
In other words, the statement is equivalent to:

```cpp
res = static_cast<int64_t>(false ? static_cast<uint32_t>(some_val)
                                 : static_cast<uint32_t>(-1));
// due to the "false ?", this is equivalent to:
res = static_cast<int64_t>(UINT32_MAX - static_cast<uint32_t>(1));
```

`int64_t` can represent all values of `uint32_t`, so the conversion `uint32_t -> int64_t` doesn't change the value.

Converting `int` to `unsigned` in such cases is decision that dates back to C (see also [What happens when I mix signed and unsigned types in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25609091/5740428)).

Answer (score 2):

The common type of the expression `(false) ? static_cast<uint32_t>(some_val) : (-1)` is either `uint32_t` or `unsigned int`, but on many platforms those are the same type. The type you are assigning to doesn't change that.